# Android wifi state permission

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

My app is communicating with another device by wifi.
I tried to ask all permissions at app's start, but is never asked about wifi.
By the way, every time I need to change wifi, user must give permission.
How can I ask for change wifi state permission once and never bother user again?

Sample of code that I used to change wifi is below

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
    if (!key.equals(""))
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

    final int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);

    Log.d("Network ID", Integer.toString(netId));
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
```

The permission my phone is asked about below
[image]

It is Russian. Translation is "Would you give this app a permission to turn on/turn off WIFI?".

I tested it on another phone, and it keeps happening. Both phones is xiaomi and have their own android version MIUI.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code snippet in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And use this code:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false); // activate/deactivate wifi
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare it in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Android > 6.0 user prompted runtime permission is NOT required for CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, because it is one of the safe ones.

If something is still goes wrong, please provide code sample which you are using.

**UPD:**

Tested your code on Samsung J5 with Android 6.0 and everithing works fine.

Also you are using deprecated methods. You need to use something like this for >= Android.O

In manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

And code:

```
        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
builder.setSsid("SSID");
builder.setWpa2Passphrase("PASSWORD");

WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();

NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder1 = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
networkRequestBuilder1.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
networkRequestBuilder1.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);

NetworkRequest nr = networkRequestBuilder1.build();
final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new
        ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                Log.d("TEST", "onAvailable:" + network);
                cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
            }
        };
cm.requestNetwork(nr, networkCallback);
```

Comment: I already have both <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: @Verde could you please explain this more detailed "every time I need to change wifi, user must give permission"? Or provide source code which you use to change wifi state?

Comment: Added sample into question

Comment: You are testing on real device?

Comment: Yes, I test on real phone. It keeps asking me for permissinon to change wifi.

Comment: What kind of permission? Could you please send screenshot oк exact message text? And on what device you are testing with what android os version?

Comment: I added a screenshot of it and some more info.

Comment: Please comment your code with wifi operations, add this code WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true); , turn wifi off and try to run it. Will it request any permission?